# ProxyPass / ProxyPassReverse vs. simple RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, mod-proxy, apache2.4

I'd like to redirect traffic from http://198.51.100.13/site1/ to the server's port 1001.

1. This works (but don't forget to `a2enmod proxy` and `a2enmod proxy_http` first!):

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/site1(.*)$ http://localhost:1001$1 [P,L]
   ```
2. I have read that it should be possible to do it that way, instead of using `RewriteRule`:

   ```
   ProxyPass /site1 http://localhost:1001/
   ProxyPassReverse /site1 http://localhost:1001/
   ```

However, it doesn't work for me for now (`Proxy Error, The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request GET /site1. Reason: DNS lookup failure for: localhost:1001site1`).

Question: **What's the benefit of solution 2 instead of simple URL rewriting (solution 1)?**  and how to correct solution 2 to make it work?